# Transform:translate does not work for links in the div

Tags: html, css

As in title i have a problem. Links inside a div does not translate on hover. Without div it works perfectly.

```css
.navbar__link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}

.navbar__link:hover{
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(-4px);
    transition: all .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__leftside">
  <a class=" navbar__link" href="{% url 'home-page' %}">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar__rightside">
  <a class= "navbar__link" href="{% url 'profile-page' %}">Profile</a>
  <a class="navbar__link" href="{% url 'logout-page' %}">Logout</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block;` to your `.navbar__link` in css.

Please refer to the official [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on `transform` css property.